# how error handling in FadeInImage.assetNetwork widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

scenario is, some users don't upload image. `500 error` is coming on console.
how to handle error?

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
  placeholder: "lib/assets/images/Engineer.png",
  image:"$URL/s3object/GetEmployeeImage?siteId=${widget.siteId}&employeeId=${widget.employeeId}",
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
)
```

Full error

```
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (14374): Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 500,
I/flutter (14374): https://.../s3object/GetEmployeeImage?siteId=1&employeeId=58
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work because I've never tried it, but if you can catch the exception I did notice that the IOException class has a HttpException  https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-io/HttpException-class.html so you could catch the 500 error.

Comment: You could check whether there is an error or not using `precacheImage`,  but I am not sure whether you can handle it at the `statusCode` level.